# onLocationChanged() never called in Android

Tags: android, gps

I would like to display latitude and longitude in `tvLatitude` and `tvLongitude` (which are both `TextView`'s) by clicking a button. It doesn't work with the code I'm currently having, which you can see bellow. The problem is that when the control reaches on string `latitude = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());` the program stops unfortunately.
Could anyone tell me why `loc.getLatitude` and `loc.getLongitude` aren't responding?

```
package mk.bukhari.loctrack;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

    TextView tvLat, tvLon;
    Button btnLoc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            tvLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
            tvLon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);
            btnLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);

            final LocationManager locman = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locman.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, this);

            btnLoc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("LocTrack", "Button Clicked");
                    Location loc = locman.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
                    onLocationChanged(loc);
                }
            });         
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.d("LocTrack", "Entering onLacationChanged");
        String latitude = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
        String longitude = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
        Log.d("LocTrack", "Setting txt in tv");
        tvLat.setText(latitude);
        tvLon.setText(longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
}
```

Comment: till Log.d("LocTrack", "Entering onLocationChanged"); this line program executes as expected , Entering onLocationChanged is displaying in logcat but application stop next to it and display a dialog box saying "unfortunately LocTrak has stopped"

Comment: Can you post your logcat? So we can know what's the problem

Comment: sorry bro image is not uploading guide me how i provide this image

Comment: Do not post an image of text. Post the text.

Comment: actually this is my 1st post so stackflow is not allowing me to post image

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: You can edit your question and add the text.

Comment: i've not much experience and i spent 2 days on it but nothing happend. Please help me

Comment: We need more than just Fatal exception: main. Please post you full logcat so we can help you

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: android.view.View.PerformClick.run(view.java:18422)

Comment: android.view.View.PerformClick(view.java:4438)

Comment: ok i try in a moment and acknowledge you

Comment: yes bro you were right loc is null. now what should i do

Comment: Well if you are not getting your current location, either your gps is not catching signal or there is something wrong with your setup of `LocationManager`. [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) is a really good tutorial about it. Take a look, that might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems that your location is returning null, try changing your code this way:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    Log.d("LocTrack", "Entering onLacationChanged");

    if(loc != null) { //Add this validation
        String latitude = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
        String longitude = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
        Log.d("LocTrack", "Setting txt in tv");
        tvLat.setText(latitude);
        tvLon.setText(longitude);
    } else    //If loc is null then inform the user
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find your location, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: yes bro you were right. else portion is executing. what should i do now

Comment: CarlosJimenez loc is returning null. Please guide me what i should do now. why loc is null

Comment: Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial. I'm sure it will help you

Comment: sorry carloseJimenez, yesterday my internet connection was lost due to electricity. by the way i read tutorial you told me yesterday. i had made changes. it works buts it doesn't returns exact location. and it returns a changed value each time i click button to retreive latitude and longitude

Comment: CarlosJimenez, your tutorial is really helpful but m not getting exact latitude and longitude. Please help me in this regards

Comment: yes bro issue is solved through your androidhive.info link. can you solve my another issue not related to programming. my 5 keyboard buttons are disturbed. when i press i it displays pi, when i press p it displays pi, when i press k it displays ;k, when i press ' it my lcd screen blinks, when i press , it displays \,  please guide me what is the issue. my all work is stopped due to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the wrong provider.

Try calling

```
locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 , 0, this);
```

and then in your `onClick(View v)`

```
Location loc = locman.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: i replaced the codes but locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); giving error and suggesting to add argument to it

Comment: I've edited the code in the answer. Please try again.